# I need help in changing the content of a bottom sheet when pressing the "Seleccionar metodos de pago" button and showing the content of PayInvoiceCard

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux

I have 2 components with content to display in a bottom sheet, I show the content of the first component by pressing a button that calls the container of the bottom sheet and through props I pass it to the bottom sheet, by pressing the "select payment method" button ", which is inside the bottom sheet, the content of the PayInvoiceCard component should be displayed

*/Account Status/*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    useWindowDimensions,
    TouchableOpacity,
    FlatList,
    ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import SkeletonContent from 'react-native-skeleton-content';

import { FadeInView, BottomSheet } from './../../../components';
import { useAppDispatch } from './../../../redux/hooks';
import {
    useGetStatusQuery,
    accountStatusApi,
} from './../../../services/accountService';
import { PayGlobalIcon } from './../../../Icons';
import { InvoiceCard, SelectInvoiceCard, PayInvoiceCard } from './components';
import { mergeInvoices } from './../../../helpers/accountStatus';
import { Provider } from 'react-native-paper';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import styles from './AccountStatusStyle';

function InvoiceCardMemo({ invoice, isLoading }: any) {
    const invoiceCardComponent = useMemo(() => {
        return (
            <InvoiceCard invoice={invoice} isLoading={isLoading || invoice === 'x'} />
        );
    }, [invoice, isLoading]);
    return invoiceCardComponent;
}

const AccountStateScreen = () => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [image, setImage] = useState({});
    const [contentc, setContent] = useState({});

    const onPressCard = (content: any) => {
        setShow(true), setContent(content);
        //setContent(content)setImage(logo),;
    };
    
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    const [invoiceList, setInvoiceList] = useState(Array.from('x'.repeat(3)));
    const [focused, setFocused] = useState(true);
    const windowHeight = useWindowDimensions().height;

    const onRefreshInvoices = () => {
    
        dispatch(accountStatusApi.util.invalidateTags(['AccountStatus']));
    };

    

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isLoading && !isFetching && data) {
            setData();
        }
    }, [data, error, isLoading, isFetching]);

    const setData = () => {
        setFocused(false);
        const invoices = mergeInvoices(data?.data.Estado_de_Cuenta);
        setFocused(true);
        setInvoiceList(invoices);
    };
    const title = <Text style={styles.title}>Seleccionar facturas</Text>;

    return (
        <FadeInView>
            <View
                style={[
                    styles.container,
                    { minHeight: Math.round(windowHeight), marginBottom: 81 }
                ]}
            >
                <Text style={styles.title}>Estado de cuenta</Text>
                <SkeletonContent
                    containerStyle={{ width: '100%' }}
                    isLoading={isLoading}
                    layout={[
                        { key: 'accountStatusOverview', width: '100%', height: 57.7 }
                    ]}
                >
                    <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.cardText}>
                            Saldo ${data?.data?.SaldoTotal?.toFixed(2)} |{' '}
                            {data?.data?.OrdenesAbiertas} facturas abiertas
                        </Text>
                        {data?.data?.SaldoTotal > 0 && (
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => {
                                    // cambiar <SelectInvoiceCard/> por <PayInvoiceCard/>
                                    onPressCard(<SelectInvoiceCard />);
                                }}
                            >
                                <PayGlobalIcon />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        )}
                    </View>
                </SkeletonContent>
                <FlatList
                    data={invoiceList}
                    onRefresh={onRefreshInvoices}
                    refreshing={isFetching && !isLoading}
                    initialNumToRender={2}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                        <InvoiceCardMemo key={index} invoice={item} isLoading={isLoading} />
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                ></FlatList>
                {/* BottomSheet Container starts */}
                <Provider>
                    <View style={[styles.bsContainer]}>
                        <BottomSheet
                            show={show}
                            // image={image}
                            onDismiss={() => {
                                setShow(false);
                            }}
                            enableBackdropDismiss
                            HeaderComponent={title}
                        >
                            <ScrollView
                                contentContainerStyle={{
                                    paddingHorizontal: 24
                                }}
                            >
                                {contentc}
                            </ScrollView>
                        </BottomSheet>
                        <StatusBar style="auto" />
                    </View>
                </Provider>
                {/* BottomSheet Container ends */}
            </View>
        </FadeInView>
    );
};

export default AccountStateScreen;



*/SelectInvoiceCard/*

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import styles from './SelectInvoiceCardStyle';
import { CheckBox } from './../../../../../components';
import InvoiceCheckCard from './InvoiceCheckCard';

const SelectInvoiceCard = () => {
    const [check, setCheck] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const handleCheckBox = () => {
        setCheck(!check);
    };
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <CheckBox
                        size={20}
                        colorSelected="#006EF2"
                        selected={check}
                        onPress={handleCheckBox}
                    />
                    <Text style={{ padding: 3 }}>Seleccionar todo</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{ padding: 4 }}>
                    <Text style={styles.counterText}>(5)</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.bodyContainer}>
                <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.titleText}>Facturas</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.titleText}>Saldo</Text>
                </View>
                {/* CardContainer */}
                <View style={styles.cardsContainer}>
                    <InvoiceCheckCard />
                    <InvoiceCheckCard />
                    <InvoiceCheckCard />
                    <InvoiceCheckCard />
                    <InvoiceCheckCard />
                    <InvoiceCheckCard />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.footerText}>Total</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.footerText}>$123.53</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Seleccionar método de pago</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
};

export default SelectInvoiceCard;


*/PayInvoiceCard/*
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import styles from './PayInvoiceCardStyle';
import { CheckBox } from '../../../../../components';
import InvoicenonCheckedCard from './InvoicenonCheckedCard';
import PaymentMethodCard from './PaymentMethodCard/PaymentMethodCard';
import { Yappy, PayPal, Visa, ACH } from '../../../../../Icons';
import ACHTransfer from './ACHTransfer/ACHTransfer';
import BankInfoBS from './ACHTransfer/BankInfoBS/BankInfoBS';

const PayInvoiceCard = () => {
    const [select, setSelect] = useState<string>('');

    const yappyLogo = <Yappy />;
    const paypalLogo = <PayPal />;
    const visaLogo = <Visa />;
    const achLogo = <ACH />;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
                <View style={styles.headerTextContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.headerText}>Facturas</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.headerText}>Saldo</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.cardContainer1}>
                    <InvoicenonCheckedCard />
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.cardContainer2}>
                {/* <BankInfoBS />

                 <ACHTransfer /> */}
                <PaymentMethodCard
                    image={yappyLogo}
                    text="Yappy"
                    selected={select === 'Yappy'}
                    setSelect={setSelect}
                />
                <PaymentMethodCard
                    image={paypalLogo}
                    text="PayPal"
                    selected={select === 'PayPal'}
                    setSelect={setSelect}
                />
                <PaymentMethodCard
                    image={visaLogo}
                    text="Tarjeta de crédito/débito"
                    selected={select === 'Tarjeta de crédito/débito'}
                    setSelect={setSelect}
                />
                <PaymentMethodCard
                    image={achLogo}
                    text="Tranferencia ACH"
                    selected={select === 'Tranferencia ACH'}
                    setSelect={setSelect}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.footerText}>Total</Text>
                <Text style={styles.footerText}>$123.53</Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Continuar</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
};

export default PayInvoiceCard;
```

Comment: You can achieve that with conditional rendering -  https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: You can reach at me at emmbyiringiro@gmail.com in case you need further guidance

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).